# ¿Sumar columnas de una base de datos Eloquent Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Tengo una base de datos con las siguientes columnas

```
id  categoría   cantidad
1    Venta       100
2    Viaje       200
3    Venta       200
4    Viaje       50
```

Como puedo hacer la suma de "cantidad" de las filas que su nombre de categoría sea el mismo y regresar el total.
Quiero que me regrese por decir lo siguiente en una consulta:

```
{
"results": [

     {
        "Categoría": "Venta",
        "Total":   "300"
     },
     {
        "Categoría": "Viaje",
        "Total": 250
     }
    ]
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacer lo siguente

```
$categorias = Categoria::sum('cantidad')->groupBy('categoria')->get();
```

O también puedes hacer uso del Query Builder de Laravel

```
$categorias = DB::table('categorias')
                 ->select(DB::raw('sum('cantidad') as Total, nombre as Categoria'))
                 ->groupBy('nombre')
                 ->get();
```

Solo recuerda hacer uso de la libreria DB, `use DB;` si usas el Query Builder

La idea es hacer una sumatoria del campo y agruparlo por el nombre

Answer (score 0):

Quetal amigo, la solucion que yo encontre es un poco más facil!

> $views = Posts::where('user_id', $user_id)->get()->sum('views');

esto es para sumar las vistas que tienen todos los Posts si el usuario es el dueño

la version de 
Laravel 6.x